# How to calculate sha1 hash for image

Tags: c++, sha1

Hi i am trying to calculate sha1 hash for image.

Is there any function available to calulate hash of image directly?

Sorry i forgot to mention .. its in c++ i am trying.

Comment: Java? C? PHP? Shell script? Do you have the image in a file? In memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the image file into memory, then call the SHA1 function on that. Python:

```
from hashlib import sha1
h = sha1(open(image_file, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
```

This will give you the SHA1 of the image, including the headers, comments, etc. that are stored with it in the file. Remember that SHA1 just transforms a string of bits to a different, fixed-size string of bits. There's nothing magical about images as far as it is concerned.

**EDIT**: ok, C++. Get [hashlib2plus](http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/), construct a [`sha1wrapper`](http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/doc/sourcedoc/classsha1wrapper.html), feed it the image block-by-block using [`updateContext`](http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/doc/sourcedoc/classsha1wrapper.html#f862f411a597be53682cbce6177e06e6) and finally [`hashIt`](http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/doc/sourcedoc/classsha1wrapper.html#88f493c77f0655eb0b8e577226c49904).

Comment: I'd rather not read the whole image into memory though if I can help it.

Comment: @Thilo: then build a `sha1` object and `update` it. All SHA1 interfaces that I've seen can handle this.